# io.restassured.RestAssured cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, pom.xml, rest-assured

Hi I am not able to resolve the error while using rest assured 5.2.0 library in my Eclipse IDE. I have added the rest assured library in my pom.xml file still the error is not resolved also removed Scope from the dependency.

I tried importing the rest assured library from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/5.2.0 But still doesn't work.It is "RestAssured cannot be resolved".

Please find the attached screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmKQl.png)

Screenshot of Maven Dependencies node expanded to the class and import statement with error message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYR3I.png)

Comment: If you have a [`module-info.java`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) file in the default package, delete it (or add the required `requires ...;` statement). Otherwise, please show whether the required class is shown below the _Maven Dependencies_ node.

Comment: Thanks , I have deleted module-info.java file from src folder . Unable to add screenshot in comment

Comment: Facing same issue even after deleted module-info.java

Comment: Please update your question with a screenshot with the _Maven Dependencies_ node expanded to the class you want to import and the Java editor with the import statement with error message.

Comment: I have updated the question with screenshot with Maven dependencies expanded to the import statement with error message.Please have a look

Comment: The import statement is missing. Did you used code completion (Ctrl+Space) to choose from? Otherwise, please show _Maven Dependencies_ expand to the class you want to use, not only to the first level and also show what code completion (Ctrl+Space) overs.

Answer (score 1):

Try importing it directly by using:

```
import static io.restassured.RestAssured
```

You can also run in terminal:

```
mvn clean install
```